# Reference Error:Can't find Variable:request

Tags: firebase, promise, react-native, google-cloud-vision

[image]

I'm trying to incorporate react-cloud-vision-api into a react native app. I am trying to pass an image which is save on firebase and I have the url. I console.log the url and it looks like its supposed to but I keep getting this warning and the "Google Info Hopefully" doesn't log out so its not getting the info. This is my first time using posting on Stack Overflow sorry for the bad formatting

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and check [ask]. To get a better answer please add [mcve] to your _"Why isn't this code working?_ type questions.

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text instead of screenshots